Odoo 16: Change the original write method
In odoo source code I have (hr.leave module)
    def write(self, values):
    if 'active' in values and not self.env.context.get('from_cancel_wizard'):
        raise UserError(_("You can't manually archive/unarchive a time off."))

    is_officer = self.env.user.has_group('hr_holidays.group_hr_holidays_user') or self.env.is_superuser()
    if not is_officer and values.keys() - {'attachment_ids', 'supported_attachment_ids', 'message_main_attachment_id'}:
        if any(hol.date_from.date() < fields.Date.today() and hol.employee_id.leave_manager_id != self.env.user for hol in self):
            raise UserError(_('You must have manager rights to modify/validate a time off that already begun'))

    # Unlink existing resource.calendar.leaves for validated time off
    if 'state' in values and values['state'] != 'validate':
        validated_leaves = self.filtered(lambda l: l.state == 'validate')
        validated_leaves._remove_resource_leave()

    employee_id = values.get('employee_id', False)
    if not self.env.context.get('leave_fast_create'):
        if values.get('state'):
            self._check_approval_update(values['state'])
            if any(holiday.validation_type == 'both' for holiday in self):
                if values.get('employee_id'):
                    employees = self.env['hr.employee'].browse(values.get('employee_id'))
                else:
                    employees = self.mapped('employee_id')
                self._check_double_validation_rules(employees, values['state'])
        if 'date_from' in values:
            values['request_date_from'] = values['date_from']
        if 'date_to' in values:
            values['request_date_to'] = values['date_to']
    result = super(HolidaysRequest, self).write(values)
    if not self.env.context.get('leave_fast_create'):
        for holiday in self:
            if employee_id:
                holiday.add_follower(employee_id)

    return result

in my custom module I have already an override of the write method of hr.leave
    def write(self, vals):
    result = super(HrLeavePermissionRequest, self).write(vals)

    # Recompute approve states switch holiday_status_id configuration if the type is changed or another employee is added.
    if 'holiday_status_id' in vals or 'employee_ids' in vals:
        self.action_draft()

    # Fix number_of_days in DB if duration_display is present in the vals
    if 'duration_display' in vals and 'number_of_days' not in vals and 'number_of_hours_display' not in vals:
        duration_display = vals.get('duration_display', self.duration_display)
        if duration_display:
            # Extract numeric parts from the duration_display string
            numeric_part = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+|\d+', duration_display)
            if numeric_part:
                float_duration = float(numeric_part[0])
                vals['number_of_days'] = float_duration / 8
                vals['number_of_hours_display'] = float_duration
                super(HrLeavePermissionRequest, self).write({'number_of_days': vals['number_of_days'],
                                                             'number_of_hours_display': vals[
                                                                 'number_of_hours_display']})

    self._check_permission_hours()

    return result

what I want to do is skip (comment) this part in odoo source code in my inheritance.
is_officer = self.env.user.has_group('hr_holidays.group_hr_holidays_user') or self.env.is_superuser()
if not is_officer and values.keys() - {'attachment_ids', 'supported_attachment_ids', 'message_main_attachment_id'}:
    if any(hol.date_from.date() < fields.Date.today() and hol.employee_id.leave_manager_id != self.env.user for hol in self):
        raise UserError(_('You must have manager rights to modify/validate a time off that already begun'))

Please not that the custom code I have in my override should be executed in all cases.

Before applying the solution that i give here to answer your question technically, you'd rather granting the required rights: group_hr_holidays_user to the involved users.
In a new module_a,  re-write competely the original def write and change it the way you want, but without calling super() in its scope ( i have commented your unwished lines here):
def write(self, values):
    if 'active' in values and not self.env.context.get('from_cancel_wizard'):
        raise UserError(_("You can't manually archive/unarchive a time off."))

    #is_officer = self.env.user.has_group('hr_holidays.group_hr_holidays_user') or self.env.is_superuser()
    #if not is_officer and values.keys() - {'attachment_ids', 'supported_attachment_ids', 'message_main_attachment_id'}:
        #if any(hol.date_from.date() < fields.Date.today() and hol.employee_id.leave_manager_id != self.env.user for hol in self):
            #raise UserError(_('You must have manager rights to modify/validate a time off that already begun'))

    # Unlink existing resource.calendar.leaves for validated time off
    if 'state' in values and values['state'] != 'validate':
        validated_leaves = self.filtered(lambda l: l.state == 'validate')
        validated_leaves._remove_resource_leave()

    employee_id = values.get('employee_id', False)
    if not self.env.context.get('leave_fast_create'):
        if values.get('state'):
            self._check_approval_update(values['state'])
            if any(holiday.validation_type == 'both' for holiday in self):
                if values.get('employee_id'):
                    employees = self.env['hr.employee'].browse(values.get('employee_id'))
                else:
                    employees = self.mapped('employee_id')
                self._check_double_validation_rules(employees, values['state'])
        if 'date_from' in values:
            values['request_date_from'] = values['date_from']
        if 'date_to' in values:
            values['request_date_to'] = values['date_to']
    result = models.Model.write(self, values)
    if not self.env.context.get('leave_fast_create'):
        for holiday in self:
            if employee_id:
                holiday.add_follower(employee_id)

    return result

In your existing custom module_b, add module_a in the depends of its manifest.py.
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': "your_existing_custom_module_b",
    'version': '16.0.1.0.1',
    'depends': ['module_a'],
}


But you called the super in the first code!

Can you answer please

i have just used the original method and rcommented the lines

But when you call the super there, it will take you to the original one (hr.leave module), like we did nothing, it will show the check message we already commented ..

And when I removed the super call (put True), it will never save any modification made in the record.

solved by
return models.Model.write(self, values)
instead of super
Thank you for your time.

u can upvote if u want ;-) : I have corrected my answer: Try using result = super().write(values) INSTEAD OF result = super(HolidaysRequest, self).write(values)

Already tried it, and it goes to the hr.leave module at the end ! I suggest updating it to
result = models.Model.write(self, values)
